# Custom Bash Script

Tags: bash, chown

I ran this as root without setting the correct folder first.
Needless to say it began resetting permissions of all files in the root of the cpanel server.

Our support guys in letshost sorted us very quickly (10/10) 
but I wonder if a script like this could be modified to "specify the path" 
instead of whatever folder you are currently in.

```
find . -type d -print -exec chmod 750 {} \; && find . -type d -print -exec chown user:nobody {} \; && find . -type f -print -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type f -print -exec chown user:user {} \;
```

Anyone know how that would be done?

Answer (score 2):

The very first command line argument of `find` is the path in which you search. In this case it's `.`, the current working directory. If you change it to a different path, that path will be searched instead:

```
find $YOUR_DIRECTORY -type d .....
```

Comment: righto so

find $home/user/public_html/ -type d ...

Comment: If you have defined `$home`, yes.

Comment: how would one define $home exactly?

Comment: The same way you define all shell variables: `home=/write/your/path/here` If you don't give a value to a shell variable, it will expand to the empty string, so `find $home/user/public` will execute `find /user/public`

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the `.` with an appropriate string, such as `"$1"` for the 1st argument or `"${1-.}"` meaning "the 1st argument if present, otherwise the `.`".